# .NET 7 Web Api Deserialize Request Body

Tags: c#, .net, webapi, .net-7.0

I have an *Article* entity:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Body { get; private set; }
}
```

To create it through a HTTP POST request, I **have** to respect this JSON contract:

```
{
    "article": {
        "body": "body goes here",
        "description": "description goes here",
        "title": "title goes here"
    }
}
```

Well, how can I do this?

I'm trying the following, but it doesn't work:

```
public class ArticleRequest
{
    public Article? Article;
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] ArticleRequest request)
{
    return Ok(request);
}
```

I get no errors, just an empty object as response:

[image]

I have tried custom JSON deserialization but also got nothing.

Comment: I would use a debugger to see whether your Action does not _receive_ the JSON or does not _reply_ the JSON.

Comment: Most likely, the `private set` are the issue, preventing the deserialization from happening.

Comment: @UweKeim making the setters public didn't change a thing. Also, the request object is null, so it's replying an empty json object. I have no idead why it is not populating the request object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the ArticleRequest class to include a property:

```
public class ArticleRequest
{
    public Article? Article { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Missing explanation: By default, fields are not deserialized, whereas properties with public getters and setters are.

Answer (score 0):

Change class to as follows

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleRequest
{
    public Article? Article { get; set; }
}
```

[image]